# Nested array in object Angular 2+ ngrx

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-effects

The api is returning an Nested Objects, what i want here is to go inside the **nested array** and fetch all the **patato-child**.

I also made all the actions, effects, reducers.

Json view:

```
{  
  "id":13,
  "patato":Patato
    "patato-child":[  
       {  
        "id":12,
        "name":"Adventure"
       },
       {  
        "id":18,
        "name":"Drama"
       }
     ],
   "url":"randomUrl.jpg",
   "example":"Example"
}
```

Model view:

```
export interface Patato {
    id: number;
    patato: string;
    url: string;
    example: string;
    patato-child: PatatoChild[];
}

export interface PatatoChild {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

Component.ts

```
  get patato-child() {
    return this.patato.patatoChild;
  }
```

HTML view:

```
[object Object, object Object]
```

What's wrong with this structure, i cant get any patato-child with *ngFor* for listing all the patato child

> I am using Angular 2+ Redux+@ngrx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
export class PatatoChild {
    constructor(public id: number, public name: string) {}
}

get patato-child() {
    return this.patato.patatoChild.map(potato => new PatatoChild(potato.id, potato.name
    }));
}
```